# What are the advantages of developing applications in C++ as compared to managed languages?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-comparisons

Hi I want to know why people develop library applications and employee management applications in C++ ([this application](http://www.syntax-example.com/Code/projects-employee-record-keeping-system-962.aspx), for example), when clearly the same thing can be done in C# and VB.NET in a much prettier way. Even banking applications are mostly in C++. Is there a good reason why, apart from the fact that compiled C++ code executes faster?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What one considers "pretty" is a fairly subjective judgement, don't you think?

Comment: Portability and platform independence.

Comment: Good question actually. The OP has sufficiently restricted the question to specific domains so that it makes sense.

Comment: The linked project is ugly in terms of code, I don't think it should be taken as example of what a C++ application looks like.

Comment: BTW, employee record keeping should really be a web app, with back-end implemented in your language of choice (Perl+some web framework, JSPs/servlets, Python, whatever rocks your web development boat). THAT specific app has no business being a C++ app if it's being written these days (though it might be C++ if it's 20 years old and still working perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C: 1972

C++: 1979

C#: 2000

Now think of the lifetime of a library, especially in a bank, plus, you get to use the libraries (theoretically) on almost every computersystem in existence (as opposed to C#)

You will also still find a lot of COBOL (1960) there.

Answer (score 5):

The main reasons for C++ for say banking applications is:

1. Legacy code. A large financial firm typically has ~10-20-30 years of business specific C/C++ libraries developed in-house, plus a bunch of business specific vendor libraries which may not be available for C#
2. A LOT of that financial code runs on Unix/Linux. While you can purely theoretically build C# code for Linux, it's definitely NOT an established technology you want to bet billion dollar amounts on.

Comment: Because those reasons barely scratch the surface, let alone being "main" reasons. The main reason is that C++ is particularly suitable for developing large-scale, complex, but at the same time efficient, software systems, and all of these qualities are requirements for banking applications.

Comment: @HighCommander4 - (1) OP explicitly stated "**apart from the fact that compiled C++ code executes faster**". (2) There are VERY few banking applications where C++'s raw efficiency is required. Most of the time the choke points are IO (network and file) and databases. Your app will be just as (in)efficient if written in C++, Java or Perl. And presumably, Java is better suited to large scale/complex (this is coming from someone who detests coding in Java, BTW)

Answer (score 4):

C++ is usable on other types of systems, whereas c# and vb.net are not.

Comment: Any system. Like anything you see around, embedded or not.

Comment: @levis501: Not 100% true. You can use Mono to compile and run C# applications on a bunch of different platforms. Check the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29

Comment: @Sagekilla - is Mono a stable production ready system guaranteed not to cause a system running a couple of billion of dollars to crash? (genuine question, I don't know anything about Mono). I know I can trust gcc or VS2008 this way.

Comment: @DVK: I'm not sure. I've used it in the past to compile code for Linux, but I can't speak for how it's used in a production environment. I've only ever used it to run some personal projects in a Linux environment. Judging solely by the Wikipedia article though, it's been in development for over 6 years now. Sorry I can't comment further on that point.

Comment: @DVK: I also cannot answer directly on Mono's stability. (Looking at the source and seeing e.g. whether it has a comprehensive suite of unit tests etc. might give us a clue about that.) But I am fairly sure to assume that if some software fails, that's usually and foremost due to a bug in that particular software, and not because of a bug in some of its base components. That's *not* an eternal truth, but comes down to probability: Much more man-hours have gone into developing Mono (or similarly popular and widespread frameworks) than into any one single application.

Comment: @stackx - the probability in question is not whether Mono has more bugs than a random app, but whether Mono has more bugs AND less features to catch app's bugs than "gcc+rational+entire c++ development stack".

Answer (score 2):

Apart from technical reasons (such that C++ is an "unmanaged" language with quite different capabilities and properties than .NET languages), this can simply be due to preferences. Not all people find that C# and VB.NET are the best tool for every task. Or the prettiest. Why do *you* think so? And why should others not have similarly good reasons for choosing another tool of their liking?

**Update, in reply to Konrad's comment:**

It's correct that "preference" is indeed too narrow a term. There's other facets to it:

- Managers / bosses can turn their (possibly badly informed) preferences into business policies;
- A corporation's decade-old codebase can mean that when it comes to choosing the programming language for some new task, you'll evaluate languages with a different perspective. You want to or need to reuse the existing code, so interop with the old code's language must be possible.

Comment: Preferences are one thing but I believe we can muster a host of *objective* reasons why C# and VB are more maintainable than C++ applications. No need to get exotic: the IDE experience and object orientation are *vastly* superior in .NET.

Comment: @Konrad, well said. I replied to your comment in my answer.

Comment: Oh god, the IDE is probably *the* biggest reason to prefer C#/VB.NET over C++. The benefits you get from the language pale in comparison (at least from a developer's perspective) to the tediousness of working with Visual C++ and its broken Intellisense. +1 for an insightful answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a factor of the knowledge economy of a particular company. For example, the bigger a company gets, or the less staff turnover they have, the harder it will be to replace competence, process and tooling to accommodate, for example, a new language. C/C++ has been around for quite some time, and many developers as well as development shops have that background.

Concerning banking applications, the reason is, I would guess, mostly because you have a close to metal environment which allows you to utilise realtime programming in a dependable fashion.

Comment: realtime programming??? Unless you're running some frequency trading fancy shmancy stuff, there's absolutely no reason whatsoever to bother with anything so useless in a normal financial company.

Answer (score 0):

Every language has its pros and cons and no one language is best for every application.  Programs in C++are harder to write, but can take advantage of platform-specific hardware and features.  Because they're compiled, they also tend to run a bit faster.  C# programs are easier to write, but aren't able to access underlying resources and can't be ported to non-Windows platforms very easily.

In short, it really depends on the application needs.  If you need raw speed and explicit resource management, go with C++.  If you want ease of coding and clarity, go with C#.

Comment: But the OP has clarified which applications he means. And for those none of your advantages apply …